# How to add a child link of log in link to my website in google search result?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-app-engine

Basically I want the my web-app users to be able to find the link for my website log in page, like we have in facebook:

[image: See this image.]

I would really appreciate if you could tell where is it done and/or if you could redirect me to a tutorial where it shows how its being made.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It's called "Sitelink" of a website. Google will show these link depends on organic visitors, most searches page, most share at (social media) of a page. Google will decide that it will show it or not.

You can follow to show this sitelinks some instruction are:

1. Unique & Valuable Content
2. On-page Optimization
3. Organic Link building
4. Share at Social Media
5. Follow Google Webmaster Guide Line

**Note:** After completing On-page optimization If you search with your domain name then first time you will see it at SERPs.